# libgdx - how to move a 3d model instance forward

Tags: model, 3d, libgdx, instance, forward

I'm wrestling with a simple cube which doesn't want to move properly forward with libgdx.

Here's the code:

```
public void move(float delta) {
    transform.translate(direction.x * speed * delta, direction.y * speed * delta, direction.z * speed * delta);
    transform.getTranslation(position);
}

public void rotateLeft(float delta) {
    float degrees = 1 * rotateSpeed * delta;
    transform.rotate(Vector3.Z, degrees);
    direction.rotate(Vector3.Z, degrees);
}

public void update(float delta) {
    rotateLeft(delta);
    move(delta);
}
```

and here's the result :

[cube test video download link](http://www.filedropper.com/testcube)

where the blue arrow is the direction + the cube position vector and the red one is the direction.

I must have mistaken the translate() method...

Any idea?

Comment: try transform.trn(x, y, z) instead of transform.translate(x, y, z), see: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix4.html#trn-float-float-float- Here's why: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17878&p=75338#p75338

Comment: @Xoppa, the world need more people like you. Thank you.